# Native mobile application with cloud storage service

Tags: android, mobile, cloud, mobile-application

I am creating a **Native** mobile application(Android) that has a lot of images. I would like to upload these images to a **cloud** and when the user launches the application from his/her mobile these images are retrieved.
Is this possible?